# OneOf return Enumerable.Empty<Item>()?

Tags: c#, linq, discriminated-union

How to return Enumerable.Empty() using the OneOf package for C#?

```
public async Task<OneOf<IEnumerable<Item>, Error>> GetResults()
{
     return Enumerable.Empty<Item>(); // error
}
```

Error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Proj.Item>' to 'OneOf.OneOf<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Proj.Item>, Proj.Error>'`

Is there a better approach? i.e. creating a new `NoResults` object with a `Value` property with a default value of `Enumerable.Empty<Item>()`, and then include it in the list of OneOf return types?

Comment: Why do you want the return type to be an interface (`IEnumerable`)? Is that important? You could try to return `Array.Empty<Item>()`.

Comment: `return OneOf<IEnumerable<Item>, Error>.FromT0(Enumerable.Empty<Item>());`

Comment: @PawełŁukasik `return OneOf<IEnumerable<Item>, Error>.FromT0(Enumerable.Empty<Item>());` works. Thanks! Can you turn this into a question so I can accept your answer?

Comment: @alex hear you go, with a bit of explanation too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preferred way is to use the implicit operator that the `OneOf` has defined, so you would just return a value (as you've tried) and the implicit conversion operator would do the magic. But since you defined one of the OneOf's types to be an interface, user-defined conversion won't work.

To make that work you can use a static methods that is defined on the `OneOf<T0,T1>` type:

`return OneOf<IEnumerable<Item>, Error>.FromT0(Enumerable.Empty<Item>());`